# Website prefixed with XXX is working (XXX.example.com) but not without it (403 error)

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, alias

I had a `Redirect permanent` in my apache config file, so I don't know when the 403 error for `example.com` started happening.

```
# When attempting to fix possible permissions issues due to 403
<Directory "/var/www/example.com/public_html">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName webserver1.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/log/error_80.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/log/requests_80.log combined
    #Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
        ServerName webserver1.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
#   <Directory "/var/www/example.com/public_html">
#       Allow from all
#       Require all granted
#   </Directory>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/log/error_443.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/log/requests_443.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName webmail.example.com
    ServerAlias email.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://webmail.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName webmail.example.com
        ServerAlias email.example.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/squirrelmail
</VirtualHost>
```

Pretty much everything but `example.com` is working in both `VirtualHost` snippets.

I separated out the logs for port 80 and 443 in an attempt to see if anything showed up there.

Edit: Actual error text:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
example.com
Apache/2.4.20 (Unix)
```

From `error_80.log`:

`[DOW MM DD HH:MM:SS YYYY] [:error] [pid PID] [client 127.0.0.1:PORT script '/var/www/example.com/public_html/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat`

Solution:
I didn't think to check my /etc/hosts file and I had `example.com` in it. I was primarily running tests on the computer I was using and then pushing to my real server.

Comment: So what does the error log say?

Comment: Sole entry in edit log: 

`[Sat May 07 08:51:19.753285 2016] [:error] [pid 13181] [client 127.0.0.1:48493] script '/var/www/example.com/public_html/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat`

Comment: Please edit your question with that information.

Comment: Any chance that example.com is also configured in another VirtualHost file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had `example.com` in my /etc/hosts file.

Here is my /etc/hosts file:

```
#
# /etc/hosts: static lookup table for host names
#

#      
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1     localhost.localdomain   localhost
# The following line is what was causing the issues. If I had had www.example.com it too would have been having issues.
127.0.0.1   example.com localhost

# End of file
```